# Alternative approach for event binding methods in Angular

Tags: angular

Consider I have 10 elements with class name as "other". Now I want to perform some action based on clicking these elements. In angular, I need to write (click) event on all the 10 element tags and call the particular function.

Instead, the below kind approach of jQuery is present in Angular?

```
$(".other").click(function() {
 //my action
});
```

Comment: Then you can use the directive instead..!

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Directive. Something like:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[directiveSelectorName]'
})
export class ClickActionDirective {
    constructor(el: ElementRef) {
       el.nativeElement.on('click', function(this){
//my action
});
    }
}
```

Notice you need to import ElementRef to make actions related to elements of DOM.